# AWK write CSV file with multicolumn

Tags: bash, csv, awk

i am currently running various benchmarks and writing the neccessary results into an csv file.
however it worked great when there was one result to check , right now i get a lot of results and i would like to write them in the csv file but have 4 columns and then move on to the next file

```
#!/bin/bash
LOOPS="$1"
FILE="test.csv"
for ((COUNTER=1; COUNTER <= LOOPS; COUNTER++))
do
    echo "RUN $COUNTER"
    cryptsetup benchmark 2>&1 | grep "aes" | awk '{print $5}' >> $FILE
done
```

the original output looks like this

```
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b   557.1 MiB/s  1832.1 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    65.0 MiB/s    75.1 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   122.0 MiB/s   155.0 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b   412.9 MiB/s  1422.5 MiB/s
```

and it would be a lot easier when the output would be divided into four columns instead of all in one

output should look like this

```
1832.1 75.1 155.0 1422.5
1832.1 75.1 155.0 1422.5
```

Comment: it's already in four columns i think. Did you want to remove the space between the number and MiB/s?

Comment: oh sorry, code corrected it should look in the 5th column, output is only one column

Comment: as an example, there is more displayed in the reults, only repeaded it so is clear how i want it to look like

Comment: did you want only the fifth column in a single row?

Comment: i want the first 4 entries in the 5th column to be the first row. then the next 4 entries to be in the second row... and so on

Comment: Why did you add 'grep "aes"'?

Answer (score 0):

Awk should work.

Starts on second line to remove headers.
Removes leading whitespace and sets field seperator to 3 spaces, then print each field seperated by commas :)

```
awk -F "  " 'NR>1{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,""); print $1","$2","$3","$4}' test
```

Answer (score 0):

Following command will output 5th column of each line in one line separated by comma.

```
awk '(NR>1){printf ",";} {printf "%s",$5} END {print ""}'
```

Comment: `awk 'NR>1{printf ",%s",$5} END {print ""}' test`

Comment: @Jidder, the output of your comment will start with ",".

Comment: Yours starts with a comma, its just that you have printed the bar from the first line before it

Comment: I expected `cryptsetup benchmark 2>&1 | grep "aes" | awk ...`